# How to display image from file system in img tag .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, file, io

My image is stored on the C drive (outside of the web root (for both local and on the server) - and this is where it has to stay)..

```
C:\\clients\\...\\test.jpg
```

I want to display it on the front end in an img tag. (.NET web forms)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Based on your comment below - do you mean the file is stored in the C: drive of the server or the clients machine?

Comment: @DanielKelley on my local machine and on the server the directory where the images are stored is outside of the project's/site's root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generic handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx). Here is a sample:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using Deimand.Business;
using System.Configuration;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    { get{ return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        if (context.Request.QueryString["imageId"] != null)
        {
           byte[] imageContent = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\yourimage.jpg")
           context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageContent, 0, imageContent.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a folder called `images` in the root folder of your site. Then you could add your image there (right click on the folder and add existing item). Last, in you web form, you could drag and drop you img, or you could declare an image asp.net control, like below:

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/image1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: @mapleafman Then you can not show this image to your site, except if the pc where you are doing this is the server, which I don't think is a common case.

Answer (score 1):

The directory needs to be accessible from the website, you can map it as a virtual directory and then set the path to be relative to that.

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="pathtovirtualdir/test.jpg"/>
```